# How can I "mount" within my process space without being root?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, mount

I'm trying to mount *overlayfs* without being *root* in my C++ code; I would want to be able to have this `mount` happen and be visible just for my own process and its descendants:

```
if(-1 == mount("overlay", "./mnt", "overlay", MS_MGC_VAL, "lowerdir=/,upperdir=./upper,workdir=./work"))
    std::cerr << "e: " << errno << std::endl;
    ....
```

Unfortunately the error I get is `Operation not permitted`.
How can I make this happen?
Even a simple `tmpfs` mount fails not being *root*; I'm running on a kernel `4.4.0-53`.

Comment: Hey, this should help:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96625/allow-non-superusers-to-mount-any-filesystem

Comment: You could try to sort out how `pmount` does it.  source here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~fourmond/pmount/main/view/head:/src/pmount.c

Comment: you have to have correct permissions on the directory... ./mnt may be /mnt instead of /home/$user/mnt as you expected.  try using full paths

Comment: You have to give it a `user` option in `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do programmatically via `user namespaces`; by invoking:

```
clone(child_func, ..., CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWUSER | SIGCHLD, ...);
...
int child_func(void* args) {
    mount("overlay", "./mnt", "overlay", MS_MGC_VAL, "lowerdir=/,upperdir=./upper,workdir=./work");
    ...
}
```

Ideally you would also want to setup the `/proc/<pid>/uid_map` and `/proc/<id>/gid_map` for better execution.
Probably the best example can be found on the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html).